# Randomly change character in python list

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have sequences generated by python code like this:

> TTTTTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

I would like to iterate through them, and change every character with certain % to N, like 0.2%, otherwise leave it to the original character. How can i do it?

Comment: Why is this closed? Question is perfectly clear

Answer (score 2):

You can use random int for this, like this:

```
import random

for i in range(len(your_list)):
    if random.randint(0,1000)<2: #0.2%chance
       your_list[i] = 'N'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `random.random()` in a generator expression and `join` back to a string.

```
import random                                                           
s = "TTTTTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
p = 0.002
s2 = "".join("N" if random.random() <= p else c for c in s)
```

Comment: thanks, it's working perfectly!